# How to decrease vertical spacing in cases environment?

Tags: spacing, cases

I would like to use a cases environment, but with my baselinestretch at 2, its vertical spacing is way too excessive (whereas I noticed the vertical spacing using a baselinestretch at 1 looks perfect). How can I decrease the vertical spacing of my cases environment locally without changing my baselinestretch?

My code is like this

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1.25in, right=1.25in, top=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsfonts}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6 in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.5in}

\newcommand{\ben}{\begin{equation*}}
\newcommand{\een}{\end{equation*}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\textbf{2.} Suppose that $f,g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are such that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ but $g$ is not. Prove or disprove that that $f+g$ is differentiable at $a$.

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item We will show that $f+g$ is not differentiable at $a$. As a counterexample, define
    \ben f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x<0 \\ 1, & x\geq 0 \end{cases} \een
    and 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

which gets me

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: The `amssymb` package loads the `amsfonts` package automatically. Hence, no need to load the `amsfonts` package explicitly. Also, don't use the symbol `:` directly in a math context; instead, write `\colon`.

Answer (score 7):

I am assuming that you wish to reset `\baselinestretch` to 1 whenever you're in a display-math environment. Note that a `cases` environment can occur in both display-math and inline-math settings. Of course, it's probably fair to say that the former is far more common than the latter.

If this assumption is correct, I suggest you use the `setspace` package, so that you don't have to manipulate the low-level macro `\baselinestretch` directly. Instead, insert the directive

```
\everydisplay=\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\setstretch{1}}
```

somewhere in the preamble, *after* loading the `setspace` package.

Separately, I would like to suggest that you replace

```
$f,g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
```

with

```
$f,g\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
```

i.e., replace `:` with `\colon`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{article}

%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} % for "\setstretch" macro
\setstretch{2.0}

\everydisplay=\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\setstretch{1}} % <-- new

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
%\setlength{\textwidth}{6 in}
%\setlength{\textheight}{8.5in}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\textbf{2.} Suppose that $f,g\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are such that $f$ is differentiable at~$a$ but $g$ is not. Prove or disprove that $f+g$ is differentiable at~$a$.

\begin{enumerate} %\singlespacing
    \item We will show that $f+g$ is not differentiable at $a$. As a counterexample, define
    \[
    f(x) = 
       \begin{cases} 
          0, & x<0 \\ 
          1, & x\geq 0 
       \end{cases} 
    \]
    and \dots
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\everydisplay=\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\setstretch{1}}` produces a warning `LaTeX Font Warning: Command \normalsize invalid in math mode on input line 25.` and apparently this is a no-no: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522610/35864

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea. But `\@setfontsize` (which is the macro that issues the warning about `Command ... invalid in math mode on input line` does little else than `\fontsize{#2}{#3}\selectfont`, so if the macro is problematic, it seems plausible that `\fontsize` or `\selectfont` is problematic in math mode itself.)

Comment: I left David a comment (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522608/remove-unwanted-white-spaces-through-an-entire-latex-book-document-at-once/522610#comment1387106_522610), maybe he can enlighten us.

Comment: @moewe - Upon further reflection, I don't think that the issue you raise about the above answer compares to the one in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522608. In the linked posting, the OP used `\everydisplay{\setstretch{1.2}}`, which is a plain mistake, as I explain in [my new answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549207/5001); that mistake can be fixed by switching to `\everydisplay=\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\setstretch{1.2}}`, i.e., to the method I employed all along in the answer shown above. The warning message that's issued because `\setstretch` is used in math mode is benign.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use `setspace` rather than the raw `\baselinestretch`.

Not only `cases` will be typeset in a not so nice way, but also arrays and matrices.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1.25in, right=1.25in, top=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setstretch{2}
% set the standard \arraystretch to get back to normal
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}
% cases uses 1.2, so we need to halve it
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\env@cases}{1.2}{0.6}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent\textbf{2.} Suppose that $f,g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are 
such that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ but $g$ is not. Prove or disprove that 
$f+g$ is differentiable at $a$.

\begin{enumerate}
    \item We will show that $f+g$ is not differentiable at $a$. As a counterexample, define
    \begin{equation*}
    f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x<0 \\ 1, & x\geq 0 \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I removed the settings to `\textheight` and `\textwidth`, which are either useless or they contradict what you set for `geometry`.

Also `\ben` and `\een` are not recommended: you gain very little in terms of keystrokes and lose much in term of clarity.