# Not a properly displayed piecewise function

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations

I want to typeset a piecewise function - a function defined on two "pieces" of the domain. The pdf file I get when compiling the following code seems to have four lines, the first and third of which are blank. It makes for an ugly display.

I have used the `cases` environment hundreds of times. This is the first time it is not being displayed properly. (On another computer - a Macintosh - the same code gives the expected display.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}


%\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} %suggested by egreg
%\setstretch{2.0}                            %suggested by egreg
%\everydisplay{\setstretch{1.0}}             %suggested by egreg


\begin{document}


\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
1   &   \text{if } y > 0 \\
-1  &   \text{if } y < 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: What are the "four spaces" you are referring to? At the whole document? Try to delete new lines in the code i.e. delete the two lines around the `equation*` environment and then re-compile.

Comment: The display I get to the right of the brace is a blank line, "1 if y > 0" in the second line, a blank line, and "-1 if y < 0" in the fourth line.

Comment: Have you a `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{...}` somewhere in your actual code? (Off-topic: `mathtools` already loads `amsmath` no need to load it)

Comment: Off-topic: The `amsmath` package is loaded automatically by the `amsart` document class -- no need to load it again.

Comment: You should *test* your MWE so it produces output that shows your issue. This MWE doesn't ([output, click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMO4t.png)). The problem you face is most likely caused by changing the interline spacing, possibly with the `setspace` package. In this case, the question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472508/how-to-decrease-vertical-spacing-in-cases-environment

Comment: @egreg  I have used the `cases` environment hundreds of times.  Why is this time the first time I get this unseemly display?

Comment: @egreg  I had the code compiled on another computer. The display was what I had expected. It compiled properly for you, too. Why is it not displayed properly on my computer?

Comment: @egreg I put `\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}`, `\setstretch{2.0}`, and `\everydisplay{\setstretch{1.0}}` in the preamble, and I get the error `1.6 \setstretch{2.0}?! Undefined control sequence`.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire Please, update your minimal example.

Comment: @egreg  I updated it.

Comment: Then please cite the error. I get not errors from that MWE.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire No error for me. You should *not* update with suggestions from another answer, but with your original setup that produces the “empty rows”.

Comment: The code that I originally had gives me the blank rows in the `cases` environment. The code that I edited to include the `setspace` in the preamble does not compile.

Comment: When the original code is compiled on another computer - a Macintosh - it does give me the expected display.