# remove unwanted white spaces through an entire latex book document at once

Tags: xetex, setspace

I experienced that using the command `\everydisplay{\setstretch{1.2}}` will remove the white space of my entire document (book style) at once. I used xelatex package to type in Persian. My problem is while all of my numbers are displayed in Persian after including the above command in the preamble,  numbers in a display-math environment `\[ ... \]` and an inline-math `$ ... $` setting behave differently. How to resolve the problem, i.e., how to force the numbers inside
`\[ ... \]` to behave like the numbers in an `$ ... $` inline-math setting?

The `Yas` font used in the following example can be downloaded easily.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{xepersian}
  \settextfont[Scale=1]{Yas}
  \setdigitfont[Scale=1.1]{Yas} 
\everydisplay{\setstretch{1.2}}

\begin{document} 
\[P(X<2)=\lim _{x\to 2^{-}}F_{X}(x)=0.53.\]
\centering
$P(X<2)=\lim _{x\to 2^{-}}F_{X}(x)=0.53.$
\end{document}
```

Comment: "I experienced that using the command \everydisplay{\setstretch{1.2}} will remove the white space of my entire document (book style) at once." ??? That is a really odd construct `\setstretch` is mainly for text paragraphs not math and it _adds_ white space increasing the vertical spacing by 20%. What do you intend it to do here?

Comment: If you asked a new question showing examples of white space that you want to change we could suggest a latex declaration to change them, as it is it is hard to guess (any reduction in white space due to `\setstretch` will be the result of unexpected error recovery, not a planned effect)

Comment: `\everydisplay{\setstretch{1.2}}` is wrong. Replacing it with `\everydisplay=\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\setstretch{1.2}}` produces the expected output, although the Warning message is still present.

Answer (score 2):

`\setstretch` invokes `\normalsize` and as you call it in `\everydisplay` it generates the warning (really, an error)

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Command \normalsize invalid in math mode on input line 8.
```

It is not clear what is the intention of

```
\everydisplay{\setstretch{1.2}}
```

But it does nothing useful and generates this warning.  If you delete it the warning goes.

I didn't have the font, but I used Arial and got

[image]

in which the digits in display and inline math appear to be the same (but I can not read the script so I can not be sure they are correct)

with the font size setting, the font size command is having an unwanted effect in math mode  and undoing parts of xepersian's math setting but as this is really an error situation, reasonable pdf is not to be expected.

Comment: I've just had a short discussion with Mico about this in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472518/35864. Suppose one wanted the effect of `\setstretch{2}` for text, but `\setstretch{1}` for math. `\everydisplay=\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\setstretch{1}}` produces the warning (and would thus be wrong). `\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\def\baselinestretch{1}\selectfont}` appears to work and doesn't produce the warning, but is that because it's OK or because I circumvented the macro that produces the warning? https://gist.github.com/moewew/60bf1fd44d1d0adc9b0a2cd8961ae68c

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two immediate remedies:

- Execute the instruction `\everydisplay{\setstretch{1.2}}` **before** rather than after loading the `xepersian` package.
- Actually, `\everydisplay{\setstretch{1.2}}` is not entirely correct; in fact, it's asking for trouble because it clobbers any previously executed attempts to affect the properties of `\everydisplay` -- including some attempts by the `xepersian` package. Replace `\everydisplay{\setstretch{1.2}}` with

  ```
  \everydisplay=\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\setstretch{1.2}}
  ```

  and run this longer instruction either before or after loading the `xepersian` package (but after loading `setspace`).

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{xepersian}
 \settextfont[Scale=1]{Yas}
 \setdigitfont[Scale=1.1]{Yas} 
\everydisplay=\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\setstretch{1.2}}
\begin{document} 
\[P(X<2)=\lim _{x\to 2^{-}}F_{X}(x)=0.53.\]
\centering
$P(X<2)=\lim _{x\to 2^{-}}F_{X}(x)=0.53.$
\end{document}
```